# Canvas to Video is very slow on Safari Lion/Mountain Lion

Tags: html, video, canvas, osx-lion, safari

I'm not really sure what is causing this but in the current stable version of safari on OSX 10.7.X I'm only seeing 3-4 frames rendered. I downloaded the lastest safari beta and it seems like they improved it, but its still dropping a large amount of frames.

Here is an demo that should be viewed in Safari on Lion:

http://jsfiddle.net/JEKAh/1/

Please respond if you know why or what is going on

edit: still is a problem on mountain lion

Comment: I don't know if it's the version of OSX you're running or what, but on OSX 10.6.8 - with latest Safari - the video has no lag.

Comment: Yeah it works great on Snow Leopard, but in Lion its extremely slow... I submitted a but to apple but they have yet to respond, this type of issue makes it impossible to use video with canvas if you need to target safari :(

Comment: :( Wish I could help, hopefully Apple can address the issue (if it is one) in a short time.

Comment: I'm running Safari 6.0 on OSX 10.7.4 and the video is lagging for sure. I've also tried http://html5demos.com/video-canvas and you can see the same problem there. However, it runs smoothly in http://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-fun-canvas. If you change the video url in your fiddle with http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4 you can see it running just fine, so it may be some codec/compression problem...

Comment: This appears to be a bug caused by a new rendering engine used in OS X 10.7+. I checked the WebKit nightly build and it's back to normal, so I'd guess the fix will be in a stable release soon.

Comment: @Jbalsas This actually is being caused by the transfer encoding... thank you for the link!

Comment: I have a problem with lagging video too with Safari/Mac. But on the other hand these examples work just fine http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ (I'm with latest Safari on Mavericks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this bug is related to the transfer encoding of the video files. If you are sending the video with Content-Ranges you will see this issue in safari. But if you send the video using Transfer-Encoding: chunked... it will work fine

I used a simple node server to test this: https://gist.github.com/3746561/c303f84866542c4a6ec2956ecf158cb9f492a7a2

**-- edit**

the above is only a fix for Lion, it appears that Safari Mountain Lion is unable to render frames from a video that is sent using a chunked transfer encoding, a side affect of this is also massive safari memory leaks... I ran a video being piped for canvas for 2 mins and the Safari Web Content process shot up to 12GB of real mem used. -_-

**-- edit**

after additional research i have found the original issue with standard video to canvas in a recent nightly **webkit 537.3** and have confirmed that currently in **webkit 537.11** these issues no longer exist... so all i can do is hope that apple updates safari soon including the webkit fixes

**-- edit**

this is now fixed in OSX 10.9 :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I acknowledge that this might not be the answer you are looking for but it's something which I've just been dealing with for a client so I thought I'd throw it up here:

They reported that their site "Was no longer working well and the animation was jumpy".. (hmm..) *Their site uses canvas rendered videos with some overlays for a lot of the visual elements*.
So after a while we determined that they had just updated their MacBook Pro to Lion and now their site was slower and less responsive. I was a bit baffled so I got them to bring it to me. To cut to the chase:

Lion & Mountain Lion require a tonne more physical memory (RAM) than Snow Leopard did (due to the new VM architecture as I understand it), I compared their site playback to another MBP with a lower spec, with SL installed and the SL version ran smoother. 
After a bit of reading on the Apple support forums which suggested adding RAM, it was all fine again, in fact it seemed smoother than ever..

Not really a programatical answer but one which I thought may be relevant..

Comment: This is a bug, chrome runs like a dream. I have a ticket open for this and have still had no response from apple. In Mountain Lion it has been semi addressed but is still not optimal and will drop frames and use a ton of CPU.

Comment: Also i tested this on a dual 6-core xeon box with 12GB of ram... So i don't really think this is the issue, unless you need 32GB of ram to view a website.

Comment: Yeah, the MBP which I was refering to had 2 perhaps max 4gb ram.. Thought I'd throw it in as a suggestion